# unable to find valid certification path to requested target (when loading RDF from URL)

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

I am trying to load some triples from URLs into GraphDB 9.1.1. I have done that in the past without any problem, using the web based Workbench, or via the `rest/data/import/upload/<repository>/url` endpoint.

An exmple URL is https://bitbucket.org/uamsdbmi/dron/raw/master/dron-full.owl

When I tried loading triples today, I get

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have GraphDB 9.5.0 running on my laptop and can load triples from URLs there. I may not necessarily have implemented all of the same security measures that my scientific computing department uses on their servers.

Partially in response to the answer from A'B, the enterprise server is using

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

and my laptop is using

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException` are usually caused by missing intermediate SSL certificates: you may want to cross-check your URLs using https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html.

If that is actually the case, your options are:

1. enable automatic intermediate certificate download by setting the following JVM option (see  https://security.stackexchange.com/a/168061):

```
    -Dcom.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers=true
```

2. manually download missing public certificates and add them to the keystore using `keytool` along the following lines (copied from old notes, your mileage may vary…), making sure to target the JRE installation used by GraphDB:

```sh
     sudo $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool \
        -import -alias "{your alias here}" -file {public certificate here}.crt \
        -keystore $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Comment: Thanks. I updated the post to include my Java versions, but that's not necessarily meant to probe you for more information! All of the addresses listed on the ssltest page got A+ scores, but I don't really understand how to interpret that yet. I'm also trying to get the keytool to  report what certificates are already in place (to compare the success on my laptop vs the failure on my enterprise server.)

Answer (score 0):

Our scientific computing servers do some proxying/filtering/redirection of unrecognized URLs, so there was indeed a mismatch between the certificate associated with the local proxy server and the certificate provided by the download's source (butbucket.com)